# Can't Install Kubuntu 19.04 on MSI Laptop (GV62)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, kubuntu, msi

I have a new MSI GV62 8RE that came with Windows 10 Home pre-installed. I would like to install Kubuntu 19.04 alongside the Windows installation (I've installed Linux on 2 of my previous machines), but everything I've tried doesn't work.

I have:

- Used Rufus 3.5 to create a bootable USB drive with a downloaded Kubuntu 19.04 ISO image

  - I have tried two different USB devices: a 4 TB external HDD and a 4 GB thumb drive I got as a promotional gift at a career fair a few years back
- Disabled `secure boot` in my system's BIOS
- Disabled `fast boot` in my system's BIOS
- Tried all 3 of my PC's USB ports (2 are 3.0 and 1 is 2.0, IIRC)
- Asked the computer nicely

Regardless of how many different things I have tried, I cannot get my PC to boot into the GRUB menu and let me install Kubuntu. It always defaults to Windows 10. I've been scouring for more help, but after a few days I'm at a loss as to how I can install Linux on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have done so far is useful. You just didn't know about the Secret Sauce which MSI didn't tell you about.

It won't go to GRUB until you install, which requires you get into a **Boot Device Selection Menu**.

Q: What is the key you use to reach the BIOS Setup during the Power On Self Test?

A: [DEL] (See your manual, p. 3-26) [This link has your manual](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/16JF+16JE+179F+179E_v1.0_English.zip).

Now, when you turn on your laptop, you will see, perhaps for only a second, a prompt that you can use [**DEL**] to get into Setup.

Is there another key listed there? Like, oh, say, [**F11**]? That's what it is on other MSI laptops.  I can't tell for sure, because it is not in your manual; if it isn't [**F11**] then you may need to contact [MSI Support](http://register.msi.com/) with your model and serial number to ask.

Whatever that key is for the Boot Menu, you need to press that to get a choice of what to boot from. It may take you several times to finally get to where you want to go, because you have a very short time to do so, but once you do, you will see the option of choosing your USB drive to boot from.

Pick it, THEN, then Kubuntu will come up and offer you the choice to install it.

It will let you keep Windows on the machine, and downsize the space on your internal drive allotted to Windows.

When it's done with that (and other questions) it will [install](https://github.com/kubuntu-team/kubuntu-manual/blob/kubuntu-18.10/build/latex/KubuntuManual.pdf) (see page 10 and up) and then prompt you to reboot. THEN is when you will see the GRUB menu, where you can pick Kubuntu.

Let the fun begin!